# PHP file not pulling in .txt files anymore

Tags: php, mysql

I have a func.php file that grabs three `.txt` files from my server and inputs the data into a table in a MySQL database. I recently upgraded my PHP to 5.4 from 5.3 and this has caused an issue where it doesn't pull in the .txt files anymore but just deletes the table. In the `update_training_db` function, it runs `empty_table` but not `move_file` and `load_csv`. This code was working in 5.3 but I am not sure why it isn't grabbing the text files anymore. Can anyone help?

The whole PHP script consists of 4 functions as seen in the whole code. empty_table, move_file, load_csv, and update_training_db to execute everything.

[image]

The Problem:

```
function update_training_db($dbt){
    empty_table($dbt, 'customers');
    move_file('/training/TrainingCustomerList.txt');
    load_csv($dbt, '/training/TrainingCustomerList.txt', 'customers');
}
```

Whole file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$totalArgv = count($argv);

// Use PDO to connect to the DB
$dsn_training = 'mysql:dbname=training;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'training';
$password = 'training';

try {
    $dbt = new PDO($dsn_training, $user, $password);
    $dbt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo 'Connected to SQL Server';
} 

function empty_table($dbconn, $tablename){
    try{
        $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE " . $tablename;
        $sth = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
        //$sth->bindParam(':tablename', $tablename, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        // The row is actually inserted here
        $sth->execute();
        //echo " [+]Table '" . $tablename . "' has been emptied.<br>";
        $sth->closeCursor();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
        die_with_error($e->getMessage()); 
    }
}

function move_file($filename){
    $source ="/public_html/b3/" . $filename;
    $dest = "/public_html/includes/sfupdate/" .   $filename;
    if(!copy($source, $dest)){
        throw new Exception("Failed to copy file: " . $filename);
    }
    else{
        //echo "Successfully moved $filename.<br>";
    }
}

function move_files(){
    try {
        move_file('training/TrainingCustomerList.txt');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die_with_error($e->getMessage());
    }

    //sleep(1);
    //Return JSON
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    //echo json_encode($return);
}

function load_csv($dbconn, $filename, $tablename){
    try{
        $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/includes/sfupdate/" . $filename . "' INTO TABLE  " . $tablename . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\\t' ENCLOSED BY  '\"' ESCAPED BY  '\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\\n'";
        $sth = $dbconn->prepare($sql);

        // The row is actually inserted here
        $sth->execute();
        //echo " [+]CSV File for '" . $tablename . "' Table Imported.<br>";
        $sth->closeCursor();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
        die_with_error($e->getMessage()); 
    }
}

function update_training_db($dbt){
    empty_table($dbt, 'customers');
    move_file('/training/TrainingCustomerList.txt');
    load_csv($dbt, '/training/TrainingCustomerList.txt', 'customers');
}
```

Comment: The first `try` statement is missing `catch`.

Comment: Where is the `move_file` function?

Comment: You're using the undefined variable `$return` in `move_files`.

Comment: It also seems strange to put the JSON encoding of an array into an element of the same array.

Comment: sorry about this, i forgot to add a function. please see the new code (i left out a lot of unnecessary code). can you expand on the first try statement missing catch? i'm not sure what that means, i thought $dbt = new PDO would be sufficient.

Comment: Look at all your other `try` statements. After the block, they have `catch (Exception $e)`. The whole point of using `try` is so that you can catch errors during the block and so something with them.

Comment: i see, thanks! i added this in. do you by chance know anything about the .txt files not being transferred? is it due to the load_csv function?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Are you sure it isn't running those functions? If you put `echo` statements in them, you don't see the output?

Comment: it's running the empty_table, move_file, but not inputting the .txt. I notice when I check the mySQL table there's nothing in there (empty table function).

Comment: Why don't you have `/public_html` in the filename argument in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?